# How to use HighStock's tickPositioner to set tick at end of month?

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts, stocks

[This highcharts admin response](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/4959862-adjusting-the-automatic-tickplacement-on-a-datetim) explains this is not natively possible:

> There's no option for using the last date of the month, but you can
>   create your own tickPositioner callback

I've followed the advice, however nothing seems to change regardless of the tickPositioner function! **[I've created an isolated demo of the issue here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2dnxqs2f/3/)** [It's just [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line) with the tick positioner added.]

In the jsFiddle example you can see my tickPositioner below. I subtract one day (`60*60*24*1000`) 15 times (`*15`).  Fifteen is random just to show there's not affect.

```
        xAxis:{
            //LOOK HERE!
            tickPositioner:function(){
                return _.forEach(this.tickPositions, function(date){                         
                    console.log('date',date, new Date(date), new Date(date - 60*60*24*1000*15));
                    //return date;   //uncomment to show orginal dates                     
                    return (date - 60*60*24*1000*15);
                });
            //LOOK HERE!
            }
        },
```

---

Extra notes:

I can tell the tickpositioner is doing something because I can:

- remove the ticks altogether if the function is setup incorrectly
- oddly format the the dates if the dates are incorrect
- not change the date ticks at all if everything is correctly set up.

**I suspect** there is something going on with the formatting of the dates and minimum tick intervals.  In the official highcharts [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickpositions-tickpositioner/) for tickpositioner there I can see it working, but if you decrease the custom increment they setup you can see a similar issue where there's no affect on the tick positions.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost I believe your problem is with the use of `forEach` of lodash. It doesn't return what you think it returns. From [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach):

> ```
> _.forEach(collection, [iteratee=_.identity], [thisArg])
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Returns**
>
> *(Array|Object|string)*: Returns `collection`.

With that being said, here's an attempt at your overall issue with ticks at the end of each month:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    xAxis:{
        tickPositioner:function(min, max){
            var result = [];
            var current = min;
            
            while(current < max) {
                var date = new Date(current);
                var lastDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 
                                        date.getMonth() + 1, 
                                        0, 
                                        0, 
                                        -date.getTimezoneOffset());
                var nextDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 
                                        date.getMonth() + 1, 
                                        1, 
                                        0, 
                                        -date.getTimezoneOffset());
                
                result.push(lastDate.getTime());
                current = nextDate.getTime();
            }
            
            result.info = this.tickPositions.info;
            return result;
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/2dnxqs2f/5/) of how it looks. Code probably has room for improvement.